# Difference between %hash and \%hash as a parameter?

Tags: perl, syntax

I'm currently trying to learn Perl and I noticed that sometimes people "escape" variables when passing them as parameters. I first noticed this using SQL::Abstract:

```
my %hash = (
  'foo' => 'bar'
);
$db->insert('table', \%hash);
```

And now, searching for a "print_r" (PHP) equivalent in Perl and seeing people recommend Data::Dumper, I couldn't understand why people would think they're equivalent until I saw an example using `print Dumper(\%hash);` instead of `print Dumper(%hash);`.

This:

```
my %hash = (
  key1 => 'value1',
  key2 => 'value2'
);
print Dumper(%hash);
```

Outputs this:

```
$VAR1 = 'key2';
$VAR2 = 'value2';
$VAR3 = 'key1';
$VAR4 = 'value1';
```

But `print Dumper(\%hash);` outputs this:

`$VAR1 = {
          'key2' => 'value2',
          'key1' => 'value1'
        };`

Can someone explain exactly what is this and what's happening? I can't find this on my Perl book and don't even know what to search for on Google. Thanks.

Comment: Type 'perldoc perlreftut', get a cup of coffee, and enjoy.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Borrowing from [Ether](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40468/ether)'s comment - look at the [Perl References Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), and later at [Perl References Manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) in the language specification.  Or use `perldoc perlreftut` and `perldoc perlref` at the command line.

---

When you pass `%hash`, Perl passes a possibly large number of elements to the called function, which correspond to the key/value pairs.

When you pass `\%hash`, Perl passes a reference to a hash - essentially the address of the hash.

For example:

```
my %hash = ( Key1 => "Value1", Key2 => "Value2" );
sub counter
{
    printf "Count: %d\n", scalar(@_);
}
counter(%hash);
counter(\%hash);
```

which generates:

```
Count: 4
Count: 1
```

There are multiple ways you can get at the data:

```
sub hashref
{
    my($ref) = @_;
    foreach my $key (keys %{$ref})
    {
         print "$key: $ref->{$key}\n";
    }
}

sub hashnonref
{
    my(%hash) = @_;
    foreach my $key (keys %hash)
    {
        print "$key: $hash{$key}\n";
    }
}

sub hashasarray
{
    my(@array) = @_;
    foreach my $value (@array)
    {
         print "Value: $value\n";
    }
}

hashref(\%hash);   # Same data as before
print "\n";
hashnonref(%hash);
hashasarray(%hash);
```

Extra output:

```
Key2: Value2
Key1: Value1

Key1: Value1
Key2: Value2
Value: Key2
Value: Value2
Value: Key1
Value: Value1
```